# SELECT Sub Query PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I am still new to postgres. I would like to have a SELECT statement in the SELECT portion of the query, but right now I am getting an error.

```
SELECT cu.user_name, cu.created_date, cu.updated_date, cu.email_address,
       cua.attribute_name, cua.attribute_value,
       (select to_char(to_timestamp(cua.attribute_value / 1000), 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS')) AS Issue_Update
FROM cwd_user cu
INNER JOIN cwd_user_attribute cua ON cu.id = cua.user_id
WHERE cu.user_name LIKE 'perter%'
```

I am getting the following error:

> ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying / integer
>   LINE 3:  (select to_char(to_timestamp(cua.attribute_value / 1000), '...
>                                                             ^
>   HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: you can't divide character with int...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name    is there a way I can change it to integer before division ?

Comment: cast(cua.attribute_value as integer)

Comment: If it's a number, **store** it as an integer. Do ***NOT*** store numbers in `varchar` columns.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I inherited the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparenlty `cua.attribute_value` is defined as `varchar`. The error message is telling you that you can not divide a string by a number.

You need to convert (cast) the varchar to an integer. And you don't need the `select` at all.

This is the workaround for your current design:

```
SELECT cu.user_name, 
       cu.created_date, 
       cu.updated_date, 
       cu.email_address, 
       cua.attribute_name, 
       cua.attribute_value,
       to_char(to_timestamp(cua.attribute_value::bigint / 1000), 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS') AS Issue_Update
FROM cwd_user cu
  JOIN cwd_user_attribute cua ON cu.id = cua.user_id
WHERE cu.user_name LIKE 'perter%';
```

`::bigint` casts the string to an integer value. It's the Postgres specific syntax for the ANSI SQL `cast(... as bigint)` operator. See [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS) for details.

But this will **fail** if `cua.attribute_value` contains values that can not be converted to an integer (an empty string `''` would already break this).

The correct solution is to store numbers in `integer` columns. Do not store numbers as `varchar`

---

`attribute_name` and `attribute_value` sound very much like the (anti) pattern called "Entity-Attribute-Value".

If you are sure that the timestamp information is correct for attributes with a specific name you can do something like this to avoid casting errors:

```
       CASE WHEN cua.attribute_name = 'timestamp' THEN
         to_char(to_timestamp(cua.attribute_value::bigint / 1000), 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS') 
       END AS Issue_Update
```

This will return `NULL` for all rows where `attribute_name` is not `'timestamp'` and the formatted timestamp for those that are. But again this will only work if the values for that attribute are valid numbers (and of course you need to adjust the comparison with the string literal `'timestamp'` to use the correct attribute name)

Comment: Now I get the following error: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "false"

Comment: I just figured it out, the attribute_value doesn't only contain numbers stored as varchar. it also contains true, false, human, etc. So I need to clean up the database so things are stored in a proper way

Comment: @kya: see my edit. If you know that specific attribute names only contain valid numbers you can deal with that using a `CASE` statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT cu.user_name, cu.created_date, cu.updated_date, 
cu.email_address, cua.attribute_name, cua.attribute_value,
case when (attribute_value like '%True%' or attribute_value like '%False%') then cast(NULL as bigint)
     else CAST(nullif(cua.attribute_value, '') AS bigint)
     end filter_attribute_value,
(select to_char(to_timestamp(
filter_attribute_value / 1000), 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS')) AS Issue_Update
FROM cwd_user cu
INNER JOIN cwd_user_attribute cua ON cu.id = cua.user_id
WHERE cu.user_name LIKE 'perter%'
```

Comment: The cua.attribute_value is out of range for integer data type

Comment: @ Kya try with bigint

Comment: I get the following error: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "false"

Comment: Might be you have empty string in varchar column which is different from NULL and will not be casted ..so try now..

Comment: I figured it out.  The column contains True, false, some words, and numbers.  So I need to clean it up a bit

Answer (score 0):

Try this. But I am not sure if you can convert it to timestamp. You might get another error while converting to timestamp. Anyways give it a try.

```
    SELECT cu.user_name, cu.created_date, cu.updated_date, 
    cu.email_address, cua.attribute_name, cua.attribute_value,
    (select to_char(to_timestamp(cast(cua.attribute_value as double precision) / 1000), 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS')) AS Issue_Update
    FROM cwd_user cu
    INNER JOIN cwd_user_attribute cua ON cu.id = cua.user_id
    WHERE cu.user_name LIKE 'perter%'
```